# How to export react bootstrap table data to PDF and EXCEL

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am using the react bootstrap table in my application. I need to export data in the format of `PDF and excel`.
Is there any way to do it. And also I want to know that `Is there any possibility of export to pdf or excel ?` in react bootstrap table.

Please help me with the answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few packages you can try:

To export to Excel: [react-html-table-to-excel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-table-to-excel)

To export to PDF: [react-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-pdf) (not vectorized, its like a screenshot), [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-pdf/renderer) (more advanced), [generate-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-pdf), [react-html2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html2pdf)

Also you can try [this tutorial](https://blog.bitsrc.io/exporting-data-to-excel-with-react-6943d7775a92) about exporting data to Excel.

Comment: `@eniel.rod` thank you for responding. is these are work for react bootstrap table data.

Comment: @chandrasekharreddykotha This is not really relevant, exporting to Excel is based on an HTML table, and in the end a Bootstrap table is an HTML table. In the case of PDF it is less relevant if you use Bootstrap or not.

Comment: I like pdfmake, but it depends on a table)) http://pdfmake.org/playground.html